# Component Re-initialized When Navigated Through routerLink

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I am navigating from Home Component to Result Component using routerLink, but the components re-initializes each time I navigate back to a component.

How can I prevent components from re-initializing?

Below are pieces of code

AppComponent HTML

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home </a>
    </li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active"  class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/results">Results</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

AppRoutingModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ResultComponent } from './pages/result/result.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path:"results", component: ResultComponent},
  {path:"home", component: HomeComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

ResultComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-result',
  templateUrl: './result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./result.component.css']
})
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("created");
  }

}
```

When I navigate back from Home Component to Result Component, it always prints out "created".

Is this an expected behavior?

My actual code has a little more things added.

Comment: When navigating component is destroyed and after navigating back it's freshly created. If you are interested in persisting data of component maybe this will help you - https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy

Comment: Thank you so much for the link!

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how angular works.